# How to infer the return type of a function based on an argument that contains a generic?

Tags: typescript

I don't want to specify the function type every time I call it as I suppose the type can be inferred from the argument somehow. Is it possible?

Here's my current implementation:

```
export interface Edge<T> {
  items: {
    value: T;
  }[];
}

export function getValuesFromEdge(edge: Edge<T>): T[] {
  return edge.items.map(item => item.value);
}
```

And the errors I'm seeing:

> *Cannot find name T* for `Edge<T>`
>
> *Cannot find name T* for `T[]`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. To infer from the argument the function has to be generic. Your functions should already  have its have its `T` inferred based on `edge` (if you add `T` to the function `export function getValuesFromEdge<T>(edge: Edge<T>): T[] `)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to because that's the only way to use a generic type for your parameters, but that doesn't mean you have to type each call.

```
getValuesFromEdge({ items: [{ value: 'SomeValue' }]});
```

Would work with

```
export interface Edge<T> {
  items: {
    value: T;
  }[];
}

export function getValuesFromEdge<T>(edge: Edge<T>): T[] {
  return edge.items.map(item => item.value);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could omit the type while calling it! Thanks a lot :)